# Comparison of row-paired values in three column

Tags: r, data.table

I want to characterize the relationship between triplet values `N1`-`N3` for each id following dt in **R**:

```
id    N1    N2    N3   
1     3     2     1     
2     3     2     2     
3     3     4     1     
4     2     3     2     
5     1     2     3     
6     2     2     4     
7     2     2     2     
8     2     1     3
```

I want to make a new column, which gives a classification for the type of relationship between the values in the three N columns, as follows:

```
id    N1    N2    N3    type1
1     3     2     1     A
2     3     2     2     A
3     3     4     1     B
4     2     3     2     B
5     1     2     3     C
6     2     2     4     C
7     2     2     2     D
8     2     1     3     E
```

Type `A` is for triplets when `N1` **>** `N2` and `N3`, when `N2` > `N3`.

Type `B` is for triplets when `N2` **>**  `N1` and `N3`.

Type `C` is for triplets when `N3` **>** `N1` and `N2`, when `N2` > `N1`

Type `D` is for triplets when all three `N` values are equal.

Type `E` is for triplets when `N2` **<** `N1` and `N3`

Comment: What have you done so far? what language do you use?

Comment: Good point @yossico. I am new to R and am learning as I go on a project. Not sure what the best way to learn is. I wanted to find an example from a more experienced programmer instead of getting in the habit of doing things with poor form. I agree that it is best to try it first and post progress before asking though. Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id=1:8, N1=c(3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2), N2=c(2,2,4,3,1,2,2,1), N3=c(1,2,1,2,3,4,2,3))
dt[N1 > N2 & N1 > N3 & N2 > N3, type1 := 'A']
dt[N2 > N1 & N2 > N3, type1 := 'B']
dt[N3 > N1 & N3 > N2 & N2 > N1, type1 := 'C']
dt[N1 == N2 & N1 == N3, type1 := 'D']
dt[N2 < N1 & N2 < N3, type1 := 'E']
```

`dt`

```
   id N1 N2 N3 type1
1:  1  3  2  1     A
2:  2  3  2  2    NA
3:  3  3  4  1     B
4:  4  2  3  2     B
5:  5  2  1  3     E
6:  6  2  2  4    NA
7:  7  2  2  2     D
8:  8  2  1  3     E
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with nested `ifelse` statements, using `with(dat, ...)` to avoid repeatedly typing `dat$`:

```
dat$type1 = with(dat, ifelse(N1 > N2 & N1 > N3, "A",
                        ifelse(N2 > N1 & N2 > N3, "B",
                          ifelse(N3 > N1 & N3 > N2, "C",
                            ifelse(N1 == N2 & N1 == N3, "D",
                              ifelse(N2 < N1 & N2 < N3, "E", NA))))))
dat
#   id N1 N2 N3 type1
# 1  1  3  2  1     A
# 2  2  3  2  2     A
# 3  3  3  4  1     B
# 4  4  2  3  2     B
# 5  5  2  1  3     C
# 6  6  2  2  4     C
# 7  7  2  2  2     D
# 8  8  2  1  3     C
```

Data:

```
dat = structure(list(id = 1:8, N1 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), N2 = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), N3 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("id", "N1", "N2", "N3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(type1 = ifelse(N1 > N2 & N1 > N3 & N2 > N3, "A",
                        ifelse(N2 > N1 & N2 > N3, "B",
                               ifelse(N3 > N1 & N3 > N2 & N2 > N1, "C",
                                      ifelse(N1 == N2 & N1 == N3, "D",
                                             ifelse(N2 < N1 & N2 < N3, "E", NA))))))
```

**Output**

```
  id N1 N2 N3 type1
1  1  3  2  1     A
2  2  3  2  2  <NA>
3  3  3  4  1     B
4  4  2  3  2     B
5  5  2  1  3     E
6  6  2  2  4  <NA>
7  7  2  2  2     D
8  8  2  1  3     E
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:8, N1 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), N2 = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), N3 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("id", "N1", "N2", "N3"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```